# How can I use React Developer Tools extension to inspect my own chrome extension (a react app)?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that is a react app that is injected to the browser page. Unfortunately when I try to inspect the page with React Developer Tools, my React app can't be found.

I think this has something to do with the way Chrome silos injected code from extensions. I'm realizing just how much I rely on React Developer Toolbar. I feel pretty disabled without it in some cases.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing - did you ever solve it?